# Pressing volume keys causes songs to skip

Tags: cyanogenmod, music, buttons, media-player, motorola-defy

Device: Motorola Defy (MB525), running Android ICS (4.0.4), CyanogenMod 9-20121116-NIGHTLY-jordan

Issue: Whenever I'm listening to songs on any song app, If I press either volume up or down keys when the screen is on, it works fine. However, if the screen is turned off and I press volume keys, it either returns to the beginning of the song (on vol down) or skips to the next song (on vol up).

Apps affected: This behaviour is verified on Google Play Music, Doods Music Streamer, and pretty much any app that has support for skipping songs while the screen is locked.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/cm9-skips-to-the-next-song-even-on-short-presses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a feature of CyanogenMod. Pressing and briefly holding one of the volume buttons when the screen is off will cause the music player to skip forward (volume up) or backward (volume down). The intention is that this allows you to skip tracks and whatnot without having to unlock the device.

If you find it annoying then you can disable it completely in your settings: simply uncheck the option at `Settings -> Sound -> Volume rocker music controls`. Alternatively, try to use short presses of the volume buttons when the screen is off and it should adjust the volume rather than skipping.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my this setting. It got implemented a couple updates ago, I assumed it was a bug and never noticed this setting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe you can help me on this related issue: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/cm9-skips-to-the-next-song-even-on-short-presses

Comment: *Comment from [LittleEndu](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/64745/littleendu):* On 4.4.4 it is under Setting -> Buttons -> Playback control

Comment: On LineageOS 17 this setting is under `System > Buttons > Control Playback`